# WildFly 8 and Log4j 2’s log4j-web module

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, wildfly, log4j2

I am working on a web application that is running on WildFly and that is using SLF4J and Log4j 2 as logging system. On the Apache pages about Log4j 2 I read about the advantages of using the log4j-web module in a web application ([Using Log4j 2 in Web Applications](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/webapp.html)), so I added it and since then WildFly refuses the deployment (that is why I have commented it out in the listing below).

So, here is my question: is it advisable to use the log4j-web module with WildFly and if so, how do I set it up to work with WindFly?

Here are relevant listings:

**webapp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="File" fileName="myFile.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**webapp\WEB-INF\jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**Parent pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    *snip*

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.10</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>2.1</log4j.version>
        <maven.plugin.compiler.version>3.2</maven.plugin.compiler.version>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- SLF4J -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Apache Log4j API -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Apache Log4j SLF4J Binding -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Apache Log4j Core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    *snip*

</project>
```

**Backend pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    *snip*

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SLF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Log4j API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Log4j SLF4J Binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Log4j Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**WebApp pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    *snip*

    <properties>
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>

        <maven.plugin.war.version>2.6</maven.plugin.war.version>
        <maven.plugin.wildfly.version>1.0.2.Final</maven.plugin.wildfly.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Backend dependency -->
            <dependency>
            *snip*
            </dependency>

            <!-- Apache Log4j Web -->
            <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>${log4j.version}</version>-->
            <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
            <!--</dependency>-->

            <!-- Java Servlet API -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${servlet.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Backend dependency -->
        <dependency>
        *snip*
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Log4j Web -->
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!-- Java Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Maven WAR Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.plugin.war.version}</version>
                </plugin>

                <!-- WildFly Maven Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.plugin.wildfly.version}</version>

                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Server credentials from Maven's settings.xml -->
                        <id>WildFlyServer</id>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <!-- WildFly Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [common](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-890) [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4089) with  `wildfly 8.x`, and there is a fix only for `wildfly 9.x`

`Log4j2 2.1` onward will have deployment error with `wildFly 8.x.`

`Log4j2 2.0.2` does not have this error but have other blocker bug `(LOG4J2-832)`